# Applying to a new position after a few months?

Tags: career-path, job-search

Last summer, my current funding ended and I had to look for a new position. I managed to find a lectureship at a university. Unfortunately it is one which is more focused on undergratuates rather than on research. At the time, it was either that position or face potential unemployment.

I recently became aware of a position that would be the ideal one, however it really is a long shot. I recently published a paper in a world-leading conference in my field (and on the domain of the lectureship) which I believe improved my academic profile considerably, if compared to when I was looking for jobs last summer. The problem is that I'd have to ask my previous referees to send another letter and I guess that wouldn't reflect too nicely on me, especially considering the possibility that I could not even be shortlisted.

Considering the situation, should I seize the opportunity and think about the consequences later? What would you think as a referee if someone who was hired somewhere asked you for another reference some months later? I normally wouldn't do this but I believe that it's not in my best interests to stay in a university which is not research oriented for too long.

Comment: Are you sure that just one publication (even in a world-leading conference) will have that much of an impact on your academic profile?

Answer (score 4):

The solution to your predicament lies, as I see it, completely in how you approach your reference writers.

I would approach them from the point of view that a great opportunity has presented itself to you in a very untimely fashion given that, "I already asked you to write a reference for me a short time ago. I hate to ask you to do this yet again, and I'll completely understand if you decline." That sort of thing.

Hopefully you saved a copy of their prior recommendations so they can use them as an easy guide. Offer to help them if they are pressed for time.

A great opportunity should not be ignored simply because someone might have to do a little bit of work for someone they've believed in very recently.

This just happened to me recently. A friend asked me to be a reference for him. He got hired. Two months later, another, better opportunity came up. He asked me again to be a reference. I didn't hesitate to say "yes".

A reference is nothing more than asking someone to attest to whether or not somebody can do a job adequately. There is nothing unethical about someone wanting to move to a better position. Good opportunities don't grow on trees.